# How to automatically enable ActiveX Elements inside a webBrowser Control

Tags: c#, activex, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser Control in my WPF Application, when I now load a local .html file that will display a .swf file, it works, but only after I accept the ActiveX-Warning. Is it possible to change the options of the WebBrowser Control to automatically enable ActiveX Elements such as flash-files?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/158175-how-do-i-prevent-ie-active-content-warning-message-appearing

Comment: I couldn't find the answer in your link, could you pin me to the right section?

Comment: Newer had the same problem so can't tell:                     "insert a so called mark of the web in your HTML documents:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
That way IE treats your HTML documents as if they are loaded from the
URL in the mark of the web."

Comment: Ok, thank you for that, but it didn't change the fact that I needed to activate it. Mind you, it is an WebBrowser Control inside my c# wpf App.